# C++ - Why am i getting SIGTRAP during the execution?

Tags: c++, breakpoints

While running, my program often stops because of a SIGTRAP. I know, that a SIGTRAP is happening when the compiler finds a breakpoint in the program. But i don't have any breakpoint in my code. (To be sure about it, before the execution, i cleared all the breakpoints..).

I'm using Code::Blocks..

Thanks !

Comment: does it happen when you run it outside of codeblocks?

Comment: Yes, it happened to me when running it on Dev-C++  as well.

Comment: no, what i mean is, have you tried running it outside of a debugger/ide?

Comment: Ah ok, no it's alright if i run it outside the ide..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running the program from the debugger?

It is possible  when your binary built with debugging in not up-to-date in regard to source code.

Rebuild everything and try again.

It happened to me many times.